# Files missing with npm pack

Tags: npm, npm-pack

I am building a npm module, in which I want to include two directories : /dist and /demo.

So far, my approach was to use the 'files' attribute, in package.json :

```
"files": [
    "dist",
    "demo"
]
```

When running npm pack, the tgz files successfully contains the demo folder, and the built files in /dist.

However, during the build phase, I added a shell script that is copying some files (generated mylib.js and mylib.css) to the /demo directory. And my problem is that `npm pack` does not care about these specific files, which are not included in the tgz (despite I can see them in my explorer).
However, if the shell script make changes to the content of /demo/index.html, these changes are included in the tgz.
How could I include the missing files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I misinterpretated the problem:
if the files were not in the tgz, it is because I add a .gitignore in /demo, ignoring js and css files.
As I really don't want this files to be commited, the solution was to add a .npmignore file, with no rule matching css/js